# How to enable page caching in a functional test in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, page-caching

Is it possible to turn on page caching for a functional test?  The following didn't work:

```
class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 def setup
    ActionController::Base.public_class_method :page_cache_path
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
 end
end
```

thanks in advance

Deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why this was not working, so I ended up enabling caching directly on `environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true
```

Comment: I'm trying this in Rails 3.1.8 and it doesn't seem to work. The page is regenerated on every request.

Answer (score 3):

My current workaround is to enable `perform_caching` then reload the controller:

```
class ProjectsCachingTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    # force the controller to be reloaded when caching is enabled
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
    load "projects_controller.rb"
  end

  def teardown
    # undo the actions above
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = false
    load "projects_controller.rb"
  end
end
```

In the latest version of Rails 2, the issue you are experiencing has to do with the class methods `caches_action` and `caches_page`. They both create an around filter to do the caching, but only when `perform_caching` is enabled.

So, modifying `perform_caching` at runtime does not recreate the expected around filters. The example above is one way to force your controller to be re-evaluated.