# Optionally testing caching in Rails 3 functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, caching

Generally, I want my functional tests to not perform action caching. Rails seems to be on my side, defaulting to `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false` in `environment/test.rb`. This leads to normal functional tests not testing the caching.

So how do I test caching in Rails 3.

The solutions proposed in this thread seem rather hacky or taylored towards Rails 2:
[How to enable page caching in a functional test in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765700/how-to-enable-page-caching-in-a-functional-test-in-rails)

I want to do something like:

```
test "caching of index method" do
  with_caching do
    get :index
    assert_template 'index'
    get :index
    assert_template ''
  end
end
```

Maybe there is also a better way of testing that the cache was hit?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're liable to end up with tests stomping on each other. You should wrap this up with ensure and reset it to old values appropriately. An example:

```
module ActionController::Testing::Caching
  def with_caching(on = true)
    caching = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = on
    yield
  ensure
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = caching
  end

  def without_caching(&block)
    with_caching(false, &block)
  end
end
```

I've also put this into a module so you can just include this in your test class or parent class.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask such a noob question, but I have no idea how to use this in my test. I've put this in a file and required it, now what?

Comment: @huwr see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156862/how-can-i-test-rails-cache-feature

Answer (score 32):

A solution for rspec:

Add an around block with a custom metadata key to your configuration.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each, :caching) do |example|
    caching = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = example.metadata[:caching]
    example.run
    Rails.cache.clear
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = caching
  end
end
```

Add the metadata key when caching is needed.

```
describe "visit the homepage", :caching => true do
  # test cached stuff
end
```

Comment: Specifying `:caching` as an argument of `config.around` prevents the block to be evaluated for an example that doesn't provide the caching argument. This can lead to problems of example inter-dependence.

Comment: FYI, this around hook will **only be evaluated when `:caching => true`.** So fetching `example.metada[:caching]` is irrelevant here. If you want to enable the hook for `:caching => false`, you need to define two separate hooks (and put your small block in a function).

Answer (score 5):

My version that works:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    caching = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = example.metadata[:caching]
    example.run
    Rails.cache.clear
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = caching
  end
end
```

Credit to Rossti, but

1. Cache needs to be cleared between examples
2. Cache store can not be set differently on examples, only at init in case anyone wondered

Comment: So if I understand well your (2): there is no real way to test caching while at the same time having :null_store as the baseline cache store for your test? I need the :null_store to avoid fetching cached stuff from development? (it happens!)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, rather a few limitations to be aware of which don't fit in a comment.

- All the (amazing) answers relying on `ActionController::Base.perform_caching` **will not work for low-level caching** (cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125014/1877609)). The only option you have is the module independent `config.cache_store` setting that you set to `:null_store`.
- As @viktor-trón said earlier setting the `cache_store` is not possible between tests, only at init.
- The cache is shared between environments for the default `cache_store`. As a result, (i) the cache should be cleared *before* testing if you fear stuff from your development session, (ii) running tests clears the cache of your other environments. However, your production environment should use something like the `mem_cache_store` or whatever else more suited for it, so it should be fine.

From the two first points, it seems that testing for low-level caching is not possible as a per example basis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my current solution to the problem: In `environment/test.rb` I set

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Also, I am monkey patching `Test::Unit::TestCase` as follows:

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup_with_disable_caching
    setup_without_disable_caching
    disable_caching
  end
  alias_method_chain :setup, :disable_caching

  def disable_caching
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = false
  end

  def enable_caching(&blk)
    ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
    if blk
      yield
      disable_caching
    end
  end
end
```

This allows me to write the following tests:

```
test "info about caching (with caching)" do
  enable_caching do
    get :about, :locale => :en
    assert_template 'about'
    get :about, :locale => :en
    assert_template nil
  end
end

test "info about caching (without caching)" do
  get :about, :locale => :en
  assert_template 'about'
  get :about, :locale => :en
  assert_template 'about'
end
```

It's not perfect, but works for now. I am still interested in better ideas!!

Comment: This looks good. I played around with the idea of using a mock object and setting expectations on the messages that the cache should receive (i.e. cache.read(<path_to_page>) ), but could not get it to work. Using `memory_store` might provide better performance, to avoid filesystem access.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to control activation/deactivation of low-level caching I did the following in RSpec. Note that I have set the cache store to `:memory_store` in `environments/test.rb`. For development environment I use the redis store, so there are no conflicts between development and tests.

```rb
config.before(:suite) do
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = false

  # deactivate low-level caching for tests
  Rails.cache.instance_eval do
    alias aliased_fetch fetch

    def fetch(*_args)
      yield
    end
  end
end

config.around(:each, :with_caching) do |example|
  # reactivate low-level caching
  Rails.cache.instance_eval do
    def fetch(*args)
      aliased_fetch(*args) { yield }
    end
  end

  was_caching_activated = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
  Rails.cache.clear
  example.run
  Rails.cache.clear
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = was_caching_activated

  # deactivate low-level caching
  Rails.cache.instance_eval do
    def fetch(*_args)
      yield
    end
  end
end
```