# Rails.cache.fetch is feeding / fetching cache in spite of ActionController::Base.perform_caching = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I want to test my caching behavior, and something along these lines fails:

```
  context "without cache" do

    it "should return the appropriate result, computing it every time", :caching => false do
      p ActionController::Base.perform_caching
      Object.should_receive(:where).exactly(4).and_call_original
      result1 = SomeService.action(args1, args2)
      result2 = SomeService.action(args1, args2)
    end

  end
```

...even though `false` is printed out for the `ActionController::Base.perform_caching`. [This is disabled by the `:caching => false` option of the bloc (I use a hook)]

If I totally shut down caching by switching from the default `:memory_store` to the `:null_store` for the testing environment, the test passes as expected. I just add this line in `test.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :null_store
```

My `action` method uses the core caching from Rails:

```
def action(args1, args2):
...
  objects = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 5.days) do
    object.where(id: args1).where(charac: args2).includes(...).to_a
  end
...
end
```

Comment: I tried to make my problem easier to understand with the last edit, I hope this is useful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, `ActionController::Base.perform_caching` nor its counterpart `config.action_controller.perform_caching` is meant to control low level caching.

I submitted an [issue+PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20733) to change the docs that can be very [misleading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).